# I need to create a text file and send it to an ftp server

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

I am currently working a program where you use a verification code to log-in to an account.  I need help sending a file with the string of numbers to a server I have.

for example:

Send "thisfile.txt" to `ftp://myserver.com/thisfile.txt`

I currently have

```
Imports System.IO.File
Public value = rnd.Next(1000, 9999)
Public vcode As Int32 = rndvalue
File.CreateText("vcode.vlo")
```

Answer (score 3):

.Net has a [FtpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) built-in that you can use to upload files via FTP.

MSDN contains a useful example [How to: Upload Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx), it's in C# but is easily converted to VB.Net:

```
Sub Main()
    ' Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm"), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    ' This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com")

    ' Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    Dim sourceStream = New StreamReader("testfile.txt")
    Dim fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd())
    sourceStream.Close()
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length

    Dim requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Dim response = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription)

    response.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a function for uploading any file to ftp server

```
Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String, ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)

' Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

' Provide the WebPermission Credintials
_FtpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)

' By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
' after a command is executed.
_FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False

' set timeout for 20 seconds
_FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000

' Specify the command to be executed.
_FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

' Specify the data transfer type.
_FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True

' Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
_FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length

' The buffer size is set to 2kb
Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte

' Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()

Try
    ' Stream to which the file to be upload is written
    Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

    ' Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
    Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)

    ' Till Stream content ends
    Do While contentLen <> 0
        ' Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
        _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
        contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
    Loop

    ' Close the file stream and the Request Stream
    _Stream.Close()
    _Stream.Dispose()
    _FileStream.Close()
    _FileStream.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
End Sub
```

example of using the code

```
UploadFile("C:/text.txt" , "ftp:example.com/file/text.txt" , "Ftpusername" , "Ftppassword")
```